# Prevent applications flooding me with Growl alerts

Tags: macos, growl

Whenever I open [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) in my school (which has 60+ iMacs) I immediately get flooded with Growl alerts telling me that Cyberduck has found Bonjour network shares, filling up my entire screen, and then some.

How can i prevent this from happening? I do not want to stop Cyberduck from discovering Bonjour shares.

Comment: You have a nasty typo in there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences » Growl » Applications.  Select Cyberduck and "Configure".  Highlight "Bonjour" and deselect the "Enabled" checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if you're using Growl. There is no option to only disable Bonjour notifications in the OS X native Notifications preferences.

Answer (score 6):

In OSX Mavericks and newer, Cyberduck uses the built-in notifications.

To disable the notifications, go to System Preferences -> Notification Center.
Find Cyberduck in the list and set the message format to "None", and you will no longer get popups.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. +1. This should be an accepted answer from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

If you alt-click the close button on the growl notification, it will close all the notifications visible.

Answer (score -1):

I ran the below commands on my mac and it worked

`defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck rendezvous.notification.limit 0
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck growl.enable false
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck rendezvous.enable false`